# I get requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE error

Tags: android, permissions

I am getting this error

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=22206, uid=10073 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

although that I added this permission into the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and this is my code where cause the error

```
            Cursor c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{BaseColumns._ID}, null, null, null);
```

How to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431723/read-external-storage-permission-for-android?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You need to add dynamic permission in you r application because you are trying above lollipop