# How to solve Requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, when launching notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-permissions

I have a push notification receiver, that upon receive, will then set a notification as the function below.

```
private void sendNotification(String message, int id, String title) {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            IntentUtil.getSplashActivityNotificationPendingIntent(
                    this, ConstantValue.GCM_PUSH_ACTIVITY, id, title);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.praiseiconwhite)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_title))
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(ConstantValue.GCM_PUSH_NOTIFICATION, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

It was using GCM in the past, and now changed to FCM. Lately, I got crash report from Fabric stating `requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri 
content://media/external/audio/media/1266 from pid=23488, uid=10157 
requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:190)
   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:153)
   at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:691)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1113)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:937)
   at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:864)
   at android.media.RingtoneManager.isRingtoneExist(RingtoneManager.java:1092)
   at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:157)
   at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:123)
   at com.mypackage.service.CustomFirebaseMessagingService.sendNotification(SourceFile:77)
   at com.mypackage.service.CustomFirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived(SourceFile:52)
   at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzo(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzn(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzm(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I know the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32617585/3286489 is asking us to request for permission. However this is upon receiving a push notification to set a Notification, and no user interaction possible at such time.

Beside, it is not my code that require the permission, but resides within the device specific code

```
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:190)
```

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Apparently it happens only on the two devcies, DIGICEL DL810, 5080Q

Comment: @Jens, for Mashmallow and above, I believe it would need to request for permission approval from user, right?

Comment: @Jens, I know that link. But when one push notification is sent, user is not interacting with the device, how could one request the permission, and expert user to grant it?

Comment: Apparently, it's the TCL device issue. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=198748. Requesting the permission is definitely not the way to go, given the problem is specific device issue, and we shouldn't request the permission for all other devices as well.

Answer (score 2):

The code clearly states permission issue.

Follow the steps :

1- Check you have declared the permission in manifest file for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, if yes then it should work on all devices till Lollipop

2- For permission after Lollipop versions search for Runtime permission examples though I am adding link to it to have a glance but you better read that topic carefully it will be useful to you from now on.

[Android Runtime Permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Best of Luck!

Comment: Thanks @Aniket. Yes, putting permission there and get runtime permission is the typical way. However, that error seems device specific to TCL. (not very known brand?), and the code resides within it. I am hesitant to request for permission just for this two rare devices, while it's okay on all other major devices like Samsung, Nexus etc.

Comment: you can upvote if it's helpful so that others can use it for their benefit.

Comment: Sure I will. Do you think my question deserve a -2? If not, perhaps you could upvote it. I think it is valid question, where the previous answer didn't address my question. Thanks!

Comment: done upvoted as I think you are new but next time be sure to check the log and similar question before asking.

Comment: Thanks. I have mention in my question, the other stackoverflow didn't answer my question. In Mashmallow, how could one request for runtime permission during push-notification... This is odd. Then now I realize it's the device TCL that doesn't follow the right convention, causing the crash...