# Android Permissions Denial

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, permission-denied

I am trying to read data from *Google Play Music Database* using *ContentProvider*. I have included the **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission within my Manifest file but, at crash, the logcat shows that the permission is not provided. Do I need to use the "Requesting Permission at runtime". If yes, how?

Error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.ryanbansal.mymusic/com.app.ryanbansal.mymusic.Requested}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/albums from pid=11192, uid=10240 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.app.ryanbansal.mymusic">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/headphonesicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Home">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Requested"
        android:label="Requested Results" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Home"/>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Webpage"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="More info"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".MyIntentService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

Comment: Are you targeting API level 23 or higher? Because, if you are, you'll need to ask for the permission at runtime, yeah.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [READ\_EXTERNAL\_STORAGE permission for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431723/read-external-storage-permission-for-android)

Answer (score 1):

I would comment, but not enough reputation yet, but here is the documentation on runtime permissions for api 23 plus. Supplementary reponse building on @Tharkius comment:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a [very cool easy-to-use library](https://github.com/canelmas/let) for managing runtime permissions. Follow the documentation in that link, all you need to know is there, and you'll see how super easy it is to set up and use :D