# SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider ur requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: java, android

i have an activity that having a browser button and then an imageview which want users to see what they upload , but everytime that going to choose what image want to "upload" i am taking error "Not responding" ... although i have put permissions in manifest...

error log by (logcat)

> 12-10 03:55:39.459 5357-5357/com.holomedia.holomedia E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: com.holomedia.holomedia, PID: 5357
>                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   dat=content://media/external/images/media/39 }} to activity
>   {com.holomedia.holomedia/com.holomedia.holomedia.Add_video}:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
>   com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri
>   content://media/external/images/media/39 from pid=5357, uid=10060
>   requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or
>   grantUriPermission()
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
>   com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri
>   content://media/external/images/media/39 from pid=5357, uid=10060
>   requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or
>   grantUriPermission()
>                                                                              at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
>                                                                              at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
>                                                                              at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
>                                                                              at
>   android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
>                                                                              at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:491)
>                                                                              at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
>                                                                              at
>   com.holomedia.holomedia.Add_video.onActivityResult(Add_video.java:48)
>                                                                              at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6428)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

```
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

... my xml code:

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="462dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"></ImageView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLoadPicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Load Picture"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

my .java code

```
package com.holomedia.holomedia;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Add_video extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_video);

        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }


    }
}
```

mymanifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.holomedia.holomedia">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".activity_launch">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
        <activity android:name=".Add_video" />
        <activity android:name=".VideoView" />
        <activity android:name=".PlayVideo"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Duplicate see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32617585/3187366

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to you log

> Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/39 }} to activity {com.holomedia.holomedia/com.holomedia.holomedia.Add_video}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/39 from pid=5357, uid=10060
>
> **requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()**

Because when the app Android version is 6.0, you must require Runtime permission `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` .

You can do like this

```
 /**
 * permission code
 */
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;

/**
 * requestPermissions and do something
 *
 */
public void requestRead() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    } else {
        readFile();
    }
}

/**
 * do you want to do
 */
public void readFile() {
    // do something
}

/**
 * onRequestPermissionsResult
 *
 * @param requestCode
 * @param permissions
 * @param grantResults
 */
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            readFile();
        } else {
            // Permission Denied
            Toast.makeText(ToolbarActivity.this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return;
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

**or**

You can try https://github.com/permissions-dispatcher/PermissionsDispatcher

It will be more easy for you .