# My App Crashes because of permission denial

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I have an issue with my Android App. I am asking for permissions to the user to access the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE but the bug "permission denial" still makes my app crash.

I have spent hours on it and I have no clue how to fix it.

Here's my logcat:

```
 03-07 15:02:12.387 6800-8893/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=8108, uid=10089 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:605)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:480)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:211)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
03-07 15:02:12.391 8108-11729/? E/iu.UploadsManager: Insufficient permissions to process media
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=8108, uid=10089 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1602)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:502)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:438)
        at lqt.a(PG:14)
        at com.google.android.libraries.social.autobackup.FingerprintScannerIntentService.onHandleIntent(PG:15)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

My Main activity is:

```
    package com.example.arjufy;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.Manifest;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MarketPlaceFragment.OnListFragmentInteractionListener {

    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    private String mUsername;
    private String mPhotoUrl;
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 123;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (checkPermissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(this)) {
            // do your stuff..

            // Initialize Firebase Auth
            mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (mFirebaseUser == null) {
                // Not signed in, launch the Sign In activity
                startActivity(new Intent(this, SplashScreenActivity.class));
                finish();
                return;
            } else {
                mUsername = mFirebaseUser.getEmail();
            }
            mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                Fragment fragment = new MarketPlaceFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.theFragmentFrame, fragment).addToBackStack("MarketPlaceFragment").commit();
        }
        }
    public boolean checkPermissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(
            final Context context) {
        int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                        (Activity) context,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    showDialog("External storage", context,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

                } else {
                    ActivityCompat
                            .requestPermissions(
                                    (Activity) context,
                                    new String[] { Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public void showDialog(final String msg, final Context context,
                           final String permission) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
        alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
        alertBuilder.setMessage(msg + " permission is necessary");
        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                                new String[] { permission },
                                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // do your stuff
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "GET_ACCOUNTS Denied",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions,
                        grantResults);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.logoff:
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                return true;
            case R.id.profile:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MyProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListFragmentInteraction(DatabaseReference reference) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProductDetailViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Product reference", reference.toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

My manifest is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.arjufy">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>


     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>``
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SplashScr

eenActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".AddProductActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MyProfileActivity" />


        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.arjufy"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/path_files" />

        </provider>

        <activity android:name=".ProductDetailViewActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

and my gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.arjufy"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.5.3'
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:2.1.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'


}
```

Do you have any idea where it might come from?

Thanks a lot for your help. 
Very much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [READ\_EXTERNAL\_STORAGE permission for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431723/read-external-storage-permission-for-android)

Comment: which version of Android are you using? remember that from Android 6 you must require permission in runtime, not installation time

Answer (score 1):

From Android Developer [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

> If your app needs a dangerous permission, you must check whether you have that permission every time you perform an operation that requires that permission. Beginning with Android 6.0 (API level 23), users can revoke permissions from any app at any time, even if the app targets a lower API level.

So you need to request permission like this

```
  @TargetApi(23)
public void enableRunTimePermisstion() {

    if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) &&
            (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
        if (getActivity().shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                (Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Write storage permission is need for app"
                    , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "request permission"
                    , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (permissions[0].equals(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) &&
                grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Write external storage granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // >> here you call the method that need the permission
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Write external permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        enableRunTimePermisstion(); // >> When user request the permission we calling the previous method again.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Runtime permission has actually taken a new shape in the recent times ... like you need to use a fileprovider, provide Uri and the likes but here is a good library that i have used in the recent times. It works well and hassle free. You can check it out on codepath.

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Managing-Runtime-Permissions-with-PermissionsDispatcher

Cheers.