# input type file dont work on my android webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a basic webview for android and I dont know how to do that my webview can upload files with an `<a input type="file">`. This is my webview main_activity.java

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView miWebView;
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        miWebView = findViewById(R.id.wv_main);
        miWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        miWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(

        ));
        miWebView.loadUrl("https://www.carlosmovil.com");


        WebSettings webSettings = miWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
        {



            }

        }




    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (miWebView.canGoBack()) {
            miWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoadining(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            view.reload();
            return true;
        }

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! So what did you try? Any research?

Answer (score 0):

**missing Permisson**

i think missing permisson read and write storage permissong 
so please put permisson in manifirst file and also put runtime permisson

check this 
[READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431723/read-external-storage-permission-for-android)

Comment: There are my permissions of manifest.xml

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />