# Read harcoded Uri from external storage

Tags: java, android

Im trying to read a json file from an external storage without sucess. Im getting the error:

```
Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{bfaa1d6 26301:com.plm.valdecillasurdemo/u0a284} (pid=26301, uid=10284) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related API
```

1. My manifest.xml file is OK
2. I am checking in runtime for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and only read the file when the permission is granted
3. When I try read the file I getting the related error.

In a second approach I started an ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT Intent.

A system dialog ask me for picking a file and all is fine. I read the file correctly however I dont want be asked for a Uri. My Uri is hardcoded.

I know must be easy the solution but this problem is drives me crazy...How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the [solutions proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431723/read-external-storage-permission-for-android/32617585) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My Uri is hardcoded

That is not possible. You do not have rights to such a document, even if the `Uri` is valid (which it won't be, since the `DocumentsProvider` did not do any work on its side to grant it). Beyond that, the user may not have a document at the location that you hard-coded.

> How can I resolve this?

Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and allow the user to choose the document to remove.

Or, use filesystem locations that you can read and write across OS versions, mostly those defined on `Context`: `getFilesDir()`, `getCacheDir()`, `getExternalFilesDir()`, `getExternalCacheDir()`, etc. In this case, you will not need to work with `Uri` values.